# Extracting geodataframe from JSON string in dataframe row

Tags: python, json, pandas, geopandas

I have a dataframe containing json (or geojson) strings that look like this example below:

```
'{\n  "attributes": {\n    "APPROVAL_TIMESTAMP": null,\n    "ARCHIVE_DATE": null,\n    "AUTHOR": "Bob",\n    "Line_ID": 1971659,\n    "COMMENTS": "Mapped from aerial imagery.",\n    "BLOB_ID": null,\n    "FEATURE_OBS_TYPE_PY": "Blob on area",\n    "FEATURE-A_OBS_TYPE_PY": null,\n    "LAYER_NAME": "Bob's blob",\n    "LABEL": null,\n    "FOREIGN_ID": null,\n    "OBJECTID": 'ab100cd200,\n    "OBS_CREATEDATE": 1704566285000,\n    "OBS_DATE": 1704566285000,\n    "OBS_UPDATEDATE": 1704566285000,\n    "PUBLIC_INFO": null,\n    "PUBLIC_INFO_APPROVER": null,\n    "THIRD_ID": null,\n    "SOURCE": "Unknown",\n    "SOURCE_OBJECTID": null,\n    "SUBTYPE": 2,\n    "Shape.STArea()": 16799.13990479,\n    "Shape.STLength()": 577.5960005080323,\n    "Shape_STArea__": 0,\n    "Shape_STLength__": 0\n  },\n  "geometry": {\n    "rings": [\n      [\n        [\n          144.0291082036111,\n          -35.82347985611689\n        ],\n        [\n          144.0292384916548,\n          -35.82359718659559\n        ],\n        [\n          144.029364226447,\n          -35.823786015331535\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02951568966654,\n          -35.82396611619683\n        ],\n        [\n          144.0295800707064,\n          -35.824085879531424\n        ],\n        [\n          144.029613980752,\n          -35.82430077330158\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02947218861516,\n          -35.82422507763501\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02929761041136,\n          -35.82413718773025\n        ],\n        [\n          144.0291976592436,\n          -35.824154407090596\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02919121839088,\n          -35.824169626266\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02905062267345,\n          -35.82429066778322\n        ],\n        [\n          144.0289505442955,\n          -35.82439118077761\n        ],\n        [\n          144.0288130108266,\n          -35.82455993917903\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02854888374512,\n          -35.82490052779825\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02847132220063,\n          -35.82495651625999\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02832377884542,\n          -35.82504769288236\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02822440835183,\n          -35.82509157718661\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02750709403483,\n          -35.82436775725302\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02772084583356,\n          -35.82425030654484\n        ],\n        [\n          144.027994945413,\n          -35.823990283035464\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02830541368482,\n          -35.82374844575233\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02863036870997,\n          -35.823518649860944\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02883537932468,\n          -35.823514392449475\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02884491186168,\n          -35.8235235761271\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02893314111387,\n          -35.823430710196014\n        ],\n        [\n          144.02898437476844,\n          -35.82343113581187\n        ],\n        [\n          144.0291082036111,\n          -35.82347985611689\n        ]\n      ]\n    ]\n  }\n}'
```

We can now assume that the previous string is found in 1 row of a pandas dataframe in a field called 'value'

I have used the following code to exact geopandas geodataframes from similar examples using the following:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import json

extractedJSON = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features([json.loads(feature) for feature in dataFrame['value']])
```

This has been working fine till now, however, I have started receiving the following error message:

```
---> 92 geom_type = ob.get("type").lower()
     93 if "coordinates" in ob and _is_coordinates_empty(ob["coordinates"]):
     94     return _empty_shape_for_no_coordinates(geom_type)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Google searches of the error type haven't been all that helpful. I suspect that the problem lies in the type of geometry itself, being that it is a 'ring' and that 'type' is undefined (e.g. polygon, multipolygon etc). However, maybe there's something I'm missing?

For info, I'm running Python 3.8.17 inside a Docker container, and the package versions are:

pandas==1.5.3

geopandas==0.12.2

json==2.0.9

Comment: If there's no `type` then `ob.get("type")` will return `None`, leading to the error you are seeing.

Comment: Effectively that means there's a problem with the geometry type in the json, assuming that the object is a polygon, how would you insert that type in?